# Ubuntu from an external HDD

Tags: 14.04

I have ubuntu in external HDD . 
This works fine with my Laptop from where I had installed it.

Can I take this external to my Desktop and boot Ubuntu from it?

Comment: yes will work with desktop also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Ubuntu installed to an external HDD on almost any other computer provided :

- Grub has been installed on the external HDD
- The computer in question is set to boot from USB
- The architecture is appropriate (32 bit Ubuntu will boot on 32 & 64 bit computers but 64bit will only boot on 64 bit computers).